# Can i add a 3.6 secondary to a 2.6 MongoDB replica set

Tags: mongodb, database-migration, replicaset

Will a 3.6 secondary node work as an additional secondary within a 2.6 replica set ?

We currently have a 2.6 replica set and i am preparing a new environment based on 3.6.
I want to add a 3.6 node as secondary so the data will be up to date when transition day comes.

The idea is to have the data up to date from the old env. , remove the 3.6 secondary from the 2.6 replica set, make it primary in a new 3.6 replica set.

thx

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to upgrade one version at a time: 2.6 -> 3.0 -> 3.2 -> 3.4 -> 3.6.